# How to create Gummi-projects

Tags: latex

Gummi's [user guide](http://dev.midnightcoding.org/projects/gummi/wiki/Basic#Projects), says you've just got to save the root file and click 'Project' and then 'New' to create a project, but I can't click 'New'. Since Gummi doesn't give much information, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Gummi projects are still not working, that is the biggest disadvantage of an otherwise great LaTeX editor. And as I am seeing the activity of the project, it won't be fixed anytime soon :(

Anyway, you can use workarounds, though they are not that pleasant, so for larger projects they may be cumbersome.

Comment: What are those workarounds?

Comment: What I usually did was starting with a single file, and when I finished with a chapter, I have out its contents to another file, and input it in the main file.

Comment: Ok, thx. I was hoping there was a workaround to create gummi project files by hand, so you could still have multiple files...

Comment: The real solution would be fixing Gummi of course, but I don't think I could do that in a reasonable time :D